# Iteratively sum over of a vector in r without for loop

Tags: r

If I have:

```
vector <-[1,2,3]
```

how do I make a vector of equal length thats:

```
sums <- [1, 3, 6]
```

I am currently using a for loop:

```
sums <- c()
for (i in 1:length(vector){
    s <- sum(vector[1:i])
    sums <- c(sums, c(s))
}
```

but I am wondering if there is a better alternative.

Comment: @IRTFM Hope I found appropriate canonical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
vec <- 1:10
cumsum(vec)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```